# Need an Sample Web Application with code of PHP using MVC

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Need an Sample Web Application with code of PHP using MVC with the following functionality and the database is mysql

sample:

1. add
2. edit
3. delete
4. update

I have searched a lot. but i can't find the exact thing what i need.

Kindly provide your suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: MVC: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

Comment: CRUD: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Easy-Access-With-PDO-CRUD.html

Comment: You might want to search Active record in programming design pattern

Comment: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you can search google with is "CRUD" (Create Read Update Delete), there should be a fair few sample applications, try Netbeans examples, they post quite a few bits of PHP. Or look at the Bakery on CakePHP, this will help you with the MVC side of it

Answer (score 0):

Look at the demo application of any PHP framework.

http://www.symfony-project.org/

http://cakephp.org/

http://codeigniter.com/